# JMeter: Can't copy CSV variable into another variable

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I am reading a token from a .csv file into variable CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN. I have 3 request under one ThreadGroup. I want a scenario when logged in user loads a page thrice (or N time). So 1 thread is looping N time. After reading token once, I dont want to read next token in loop but want to loop through URL three (or N) time with same token.

Right now I am reading data from CSV, and using "BeanShell Sampler" inside "Once only Controller". In the sample I am using line like: vars.put("ACCESS_TOKEN",vars.get("CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN"). But that BeanShell sampler is recorded in my Summary Result. I don't want that.

I tried using "User Defined Variable" controller and try to assign the value ${__evalVar(CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN)} but it return empty value for ${ACCESS_TOKEN}. When I use ${CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN}, it shows me the values. If I use some other variable instead of CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN in UDV controller, it assigns the value from other variable and I see values for ${ACCESS_TOKEN}.

Why CSV variable is not assigning the values in regular variable.

Thanks
Vinay

Answer (score 0):

If you have 3 requests, I suggest you put a Beanshell preprocessor on the first request, which copies the CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN to ACCESS_TOKEN.

Each of your samples can the use ACCESS_TOKEN, so CSV is accessed once per cycle of 3.

Each time the preprocessor run (ie before each 1st request), CSV_ACCESS_TOKEN will get updated from the dataset.

If it is the same request, which you do not wish to duplicate, you can look into use of test fragments and modules, so you can run the same sample from a variety of controllers. First from a simple controller with the preprocessor attached, and then from a loop controller to perform 2 more requests.

I think the code you have used already to manipulate the CSV values will continue to work in this scenario.

Comment: can the downvoter explain what is wrong with this answer, please?